# How to create an object globally and access an public member function in the global scope with that object?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an object globally and trying to access the public member function with the help of a constructor. But it is showing error, Can anyone help me please??

Here I created a class named base and trying to access the public member function of the class in the global scope by creating a constructor.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    class base
    {
        void privatef()
        {
            cout<<"This is function from private scope\n";
        }
        public:
        void publicf()
        {
            cout<<"This is function from public scope\n";
        }

        protected:
        void protectedf()
        {
            cout<<"This is function from protected scope\n";
        }
    };

    base()
    {
            publicf();
            //privatef();
            //protectedf();
    }

    base d;

    class derived :public base
    {
        public:
        derived()
        {
            //privatef();
            publicf();
            protectedf();
        }
    };


    int main()
     {
        derived d1 ;
        return 0;
     }
```

> ERROR: 
>   error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
>      base()
>           ^

Comment: `base() {` should be `base::base() {`. You also need to declare a constructor to implement it.

Comment: I have now posted the error,  please answer my question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct form

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class base
{

    void privatef()
    {
        cout << "This is function from private scope\n";
    }
public:
    //Declare it at least first & then define it outside
    base();
    void publicf()
    {
        cout << "This is function from public scope\n";
    }

protected:
    void protectedf()
    {
        cout << "This is function from protected scope\n";
    }
};

base::base()
{
    publicf();
    //privatef();
    //protectedf();

}

base d;

class derived :public base
{
public:
    derived(){

        //privatef();
        publicf();
        protectedf();
    }
};


int main()
{
    derived d1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, My objective is that I want to show that public member function can be accessed in the global scope and private and protected member functions cannot be accessible.How to prove this then... Here if we declared base constructor in the scope of base class ,How can it be global.

Comment: You can't declare a class function in a global scope without referencing the class .. I think you should read more about the difference between global and public :) to prove the accessibility go to your main.. the d1 variable try to access the privatef  like this d1.privatef(); you will have an error that you can't access it on the other hand you can acces publicf with the same way.. that's what you want prove is n't it?

Comment: No, I dont want it to be accessible in the main function.

Comment: I want it to be accessible outside the main I mean in the global scope.

Comment: you mean like call d.publicf in the globe scope?

Comment: If I did what you said then it means that I am trying to access it inside the main function Which is local to main.

Comment: yes, d.publicf in the global scope, but how to do that

Comment: when you create the Base d in the globe scope it calls the constructor as you want it so i assume that's what you need?